# Change Opensips db_text db_mode at runtime

Tags: caching, opensips

In `Opensips` there is an option to cache all the `db_text` at startup or to scan the `dbtext` every time it is queried by using the following line in the `opensips.cfg` file:

`modparam("db_text", "db_mode", 0)`

[Documentation](http://www.opensips.org/html/docs/modules/devel/db_text.html#idp5561632)

My question is if it is possible to change this behavior at runtime, or do I need to change the config file and restart the server every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `db_mode` module parameter of db_text cannot be changed at runtime.

Depending on your needs, however, `db_mode = 0` combined with occasional `dbt_reload` MI commands might be superior to using on-demand caching (`db_mode = 1`).